# loop once more in C

Tags: c, loops, undefined-behavior, fgets, feof

I write c program that reads a file (argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs3uR.png)) line by line

my text file is this :

[image]

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_fp(FILE *fp){
        char buffer[50];
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
        printf("%s", buffer);

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        while(1){
                if(feof(fp)) break;
                read_fp(fp);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

OR

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        while(!feof(fp)){
                read_fp(fp);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I predict my program prints
one
two
three
four
five
six

but program actually prints
one
two
three
four
five
six
six

it loops once more

why...?  how can i fix this

Comment: [Don't use `feof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941).  To detect the end-of-file, look at what `fgets` returns. If `fgets` returns `NULL`, then it didn't read anything from the file.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the last record of the file the condition `feof( fp )` is not set yet.

So within the function you are trying to access the file one more

```
void read_fp(FILE *fp){
        char buffer[50];
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        printf("%s", buffer);

}
```

In this case the condition is satisfied and the call of `fgets`  returns `NULL`. But you are outputting the current value stored in `buffer` that results in undefined behavior.

You could change the function for example like

```
void read_fp(FILE *fp){
        char buffer[50];
        If ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) ) printf("%s", buffer);
}
```